# The general formula for the integral of negative exponential in n dimensions

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

Suppose **x** is a real vector in *n* dimensions. What is the general formula for the result of the following integral, which is calculated over the entire space:

$$ I = \int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{e^{ - ||{\bf{x}}||}}} {d^n}{\bf{x}}\ $$

Where ||x|| is L2-norm of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any dimension you can use the (hyper-)spherical coordinates, in which $d^n\mathbf{x}=r^{n-1}drd\Omega$, and $\Omega$ is the generalization of solid angle. In this coordinate system your integral becomes
$$
I_n=\int d\Omega\int_{0}^\infty r^{n-1} e^{-r}dr
$$
The latter integral, by definition, is $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$, so it remains to calculate $\int d\Omega$ (oh by the way by this integral I mean integral over all solid angles). Let us denote this integral by $\sigma_{n}$.

Note that
$$J=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-||\mathbf{x}||^2}d^n\mathbf{x}=\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\right)^n =\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}$$
But one can calculate the same integral in (hyper-)spherical coordinates, then
$$
J=\sigma_{n}\int_{0}^\infty r^{n-1}e^{-r^2}dr\xrightarrow{s=r^2} 
\frac{\sigma_n}{2}\int_{0}^\infty s^{(\frac{n}{2}-1)}e^{-s}ds=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}{2}\sigma_n\Longrightarrow \boxed{\sigma_{n}=\frac{2\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}}
$$
As a result your integral is
$$
\boxed{I_n=2\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}}
$$